# How to install Berkeley DB 4.8 on Linux?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, linux

The [Unix build notes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md) do not show how to install version 4.8 apart from saying

> BerkeleyDB is required for the wallet. Ubuntu and Debian have their 
>       own libdb-dev and libdb++-dev packages, but these will install 
>       BerkeleyDB 5.1 or later. This will break binary wallet compatibility 
>       with the distributed executables, which are based on BerkeleyDB 4.8.If you do not care about wallet compatibility, pass --with-incompatible-bdb to configure. Otherwise, you can build from self-compiled depends (see above).

The referenced [README.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/depends/README.md) from the quoted

> Now, you can either build from self-compiled depends or install the
>   required dependencies:

does not discuss BerkeleyDB 4.8.

I know there is `./contrib/install_db4.sh` in the source for installing BerkeleyDB 4.8 but it abords on my Ubuntu with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to git.savannah.gnu.org port 443: No route to host`.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile it using this script in the Bitcoin Core repository:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/install_db4.sh . It will give you instructions about how to then `./configure` with this compiled version in order to build the project.

Instructions about building Bitcoin Core are available in the [`/doc`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/doc) folder, for Unix systems it is at
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://88plug.com/linux/install-berkeley-4-8-db-libs-on-ubuntu-16-04/) with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

---

Also, [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216846) says:

> The newer libdb should work on most coin daemons, the issue you might find is that the database files (wallet.dat in particular) isn't compatible with all other systems if they're built on an older libdb.

That corresponds to the following line from the bitcoin core github:

> This will break binary wallet compatibility with the distributed executables, which are based on BerkeleyDB 4.8.

So, having a newer BerkeleyDB is only a problem, if you want to use your `wallet.dat` on another system and this other system happens to use BerkeleyDB 4.8 - which is the case for the `bitcoind` executables which are downloadable from the project itself.

But if you only use the wallet on your own system or, if you migrate it, you use a system with the newer BerkeleyDB also, then there should be no problems.

Answer (score -1):

`brew install berkeley-db@4` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

this fixed my problem in kali
i used
sudo apt install libdb
and then pip install bsddb3 and it was able to find the local berkely installation and complete the install
thanks soo much